# Using Find-Item to get equivalent result of Get-Item

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have got

```
$eventsPath = "/sitecore/content/Global Content/Events"
$templateId = "{EBE88C21-4035-4266-9647-B4C88F1BC000}"

# Function to get data and print on the screen
function Print-EventData($item) {
    $nId = $item.ID
    $title = $item.Name
    
    $created = $item.Statistics.Created
    $changed = $item.Statistics.Updated
    
    $eventDetails = $item.PSFields.'Event Title'.value
   #image

    $imagePath = $item.PsFields.'image'.value
    
    #searchTags
    $searchTags = $item.PsFields.'Search Tags'.GetItems() | ForEach-Object { $_.DisplayName }
    $searchTagsString = if ($searchTags) { $searchTags -join '|' } else { "NA" }

    #field_domain_acess
    $relatedSiteDetails = $item.PsFields.'Related Site'.GetItems() | ForEach-Object { $_.DisplayName }
    $relatedSite = if ($relatedSiteDetails) { $relatedSiteDetails -join '|' } else { "NA" }

    #field_event_catogery
    $eventCategory =  $item.PsFields.'Event Category'.GetItems() | ForEach-Object { $_.DisplayName }
    $eventCategoryString =  if ($eventCategory) { $eventCategory -join '|' } else { "NA" }
   

   
 
   
   
   
   
   
    #Write-Host "$relatedSiteDetails"
    Write-Host "Item ID:$nId , title = $title , Created: $created, changed: $changed, Image Path: $imagePath, Searchtags: $searchTagsString, field_domain_acess: $relatedSite "
}

# Get the root item
$rootItem = Get-Item -Path $eventsPath

# Process the root item and its children
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -Path $rootItem.FullPath -Recurse) {
    if ($item.TemplateID -eq $templateId) {
        Print-EventData -item $item
    }
}
```

how can I get the equivalent result in master index using Find-Item

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by following script.

```
$eventsPath = "/sitecore/content/Global Content/Events"
$eventsItem = Get-Item -Path $eventsPath
$templateId = [ID]::Parse("{EBE88C21-4035-4266-9647-B4C88F1BC000}")

$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Where = 'TemplateId = @0 And Paths.Contains(@1)'
    WhereValues = $templateId, $eventsItem.Id
}

Find-Item @props
```

Do checkout examples on this page for any modification - https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/find-item

Answer (score 0):

Following are a few parameters that we can use with `Find-Item`:

- Index: Where we specify the name of the index to use.
- Criteria: Where we specify the Search Filter
- First: Where we can specify the number of results to return
- Skip: Where we can specify the number of results to be skipped before returning the result
- Where: Where we can specify Dynamic Linq to filter results
- WhereValue: Where we can specify Array of values that will be used by -Where Linq statement

Here is one example, you can use.

```
$FilterCriteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = "Event Details"},
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/Events" }
)
Find-Item -Index "sitecore_master_index" -Criteria $FilterCriteria
```

Every Filter has three imp parts: Field, Filter, and Value.

- Filter: Where we specify the operator for evaluating the condition. Ex-  -
- Equals, StartsWith, Contains, EndsWith, LessThan, GreaterThan etc.
- Field: Where we can specify the name of the indexed field that we want to use in filtering condition.
  Value: Value of the field for satisfying the condition.

Hope this helps.